# Debug Error in SSIS script

Tags: c#, ssis

I am new To SSIS packages and I am trying to create a SSIS script task which creates an empty file and file name should be like "FileName__yyyymmdd__.csv". 
I am trying to compile this code but it is taking ages to compile and isn't even showing any error but when I execute the package as whole, the package gets failed at script task.

The code below is written in Main function:

```
    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    String FileLoc="D:\\Folder\\" ;
    String BaseName="FileName__";
    DateTime dt= DateTime.Now;
    String yr= dt.Year.ToString();
    String mm= dt.Month.ToString();
    String dd= dt.Day.ToString();
    String FileName = BaseName + yr + mm + dd + "__"+".csv";
    File.Create(FileLoc+FileName).Dispose();
```

Could anybody please highlight the error?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filename can be generated in 1 line.

Also, you can set a breakpoint in your Script task and then execute the package in Debug mode, after selecting the package as the Startup package.

You are doing a couple of things incorrectly (or inefficiently). I've corrected your code. Try the following code. It works.

You'll need the following `using` statements on top of your script `.cs` file.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Globalization;
```

And inside your main function, the following code as appropriate.

```
string fileLocation = @"D:\Folder\" ;
string fileNamePrefix = "FileName__";
string filename = Path.Combine(fileLocation, fileNamePrefix 
                                   + DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) 
                                   + "__.csv"); 

// This will print "D:\Folder\FileName__20160920__.csv". 
Console.WriteLine(filename);

// if file does not exist, create it.
if (! File.Exists(filename))
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(filename))
    {
       // write data into file using sw.WriteLine(...) or something similar
    }
}
Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

#### Here's a .NetFiddle just for the C# part of it. https://dotnetfiddle.net/UQRhqB